# Meter mi función en un for para no repetir tanto código

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber si puedo meter mi función dentro de un `for` para no repetir tanto código.

```javascript
function RoundOf16() {
    console.log("Round of 16");

    roundOf16[0][0] = RandomPick(group[0]); // A1
    roundOf16[0][1] = RandomPick(group[1]); // B2
    roundOf16[1][0] = RandomPick(group[2]); // C1
    roundOf16[1][1] = RandomPick(group[3]); // D2
    roundOf16[2][0] = RandomPick(group[4]); // E1
    roundOf16[2][1] = RandomPick(group[5]); // F2
    roundOf16[3][0] = RandomPick(group[6]); // G1
    roundOf16[3][1] = RandomPick(group[7]); // H2

    roundOf16[4][1] = RandomPick(group[0]); // A2
    roundOf16[4][0] = RandomPick(group[1]); // B1
    roundOf16[5][1] = RandomPick(group[2]); // C2
    roundOf16[5][0] = RandomPick(group[3]); // D1
    roundOf16[6][1] = RandomPick(group[4]); // E2
    roundOf16[6][0] = RandomPick(group[5]); // F1
    roundOf16[7][1] = RandomPick(group[6]); // G2
    roundOf16[7][0] = RandomPick(group[7]); // H1
    
    console.log(roundOf16);
}
```

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta: sí. **¿Qué has intentado?** Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Haremos un array de 8 elementos: uno para cada partido.
Cada uno de esos elementos será una pareja de dos números:
cada número indica a qué grupo pertenece el equipo.

```javascript
const parejas = [
    [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7],
    [1, 0], [3, 2], [5, 4], [7, 6]
];
```

Ahora simplemente rellenamos los elementos de `roundOf16`.

```javascript
for (let i = 0; i < parejas.length; i++) {
    const [groupIndex1, groupIndex2] = parejas[i];
    roundOf16[i][0] = RandomPick(group[groupIndex1]);
    roundOf16[i][1] = RandomPick(group[groupIndex2]);
}
```

Comment: Maestro, muy buen ojo, se me había pasado lo de la inversión en el orden, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pides es bastante sencillo...

```
let orden = 0;

   // el for externo recorre las filas
for( let i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {

       // el for interno recorre las columnas
    for( let k = 0; k < 2; k++ ) {
        roundOf16[ i ][ k ] = RandomPick( group[ orden ] );

           // aumentamos el valor de "orden" y si es igual a "8" lo establecemos en "0"
        orden ++;
        if( orden == 8) {
            orden = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva...

@Jorge Luis, me puso en sobre-aviso del cambio de orden en las columnas, algo que se me había pasado por alto, agrego el código adaptado a ese cambio...

Versión "A":

```
let orden = 0;
let cambio = false;
    
for( let i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) { 
    if( cambio ) {
         descendente( i );        
    }
    else {
        ascendente( i );
    }   
    if( orden == 8) {
        orden = 0;
        cambio = true;
    }
}

function ascendente( i ) {
    for( let k = 0; k < 2; k ++ ) {
        console.log( i + " " + k + " " + orden );
        orden ++;
    }
}

function descendente( i ) {
    for( let k = 1; k > -1; k -- ) {
        console.log( i + " " + k + " " + orden );
        orden ++;
    }
}
```

El funcionamiento es super sencillo, si estamos en la primer mitad, invocamos la función **ascendente** y si no a **descendente**, una usa un bucle "normal" y la otra uno descendente.

Versión "B":
Esta versión, hace exactamente lo mismo, pero realiza la modificación del bucle "in situ"...

```
let orden = 0;
let cambio = false;
let aum = 1;
for( let i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    let condicion = true;
    let k = 0;

      # si pasamos la mitad,  cambiamos la inicialización de "k" y "aum".
    if( cambio ) {
        k = 1;
        aum = -1;
    }
    while( condicion ) {
        console.log( i + " " + k + " " + orden );

           # aumentamos "orden" y "k"
        orden++;    
        k += aum;

          # inicializamos "condicion" y si pasamos la mitad, la modificamos
        condicion = k < 2
        if( cambio ) {
           condicion = k >= 0;
        }
        if( orden == 8 ) {
            orden = 0;
            cambio = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Todo esto para decir que la respuesta de Jorge, es más elegante!.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer maestro!.

Comment: Este código no produce el mismo resultado que el de la pregunta. Con este código el elemento de `roundOf16[4][0]` se elegirá del grupo 0 mientras que en la pregunta original se elige del grupo 1.